# Ansible.Run task localy after remote/

Tags: ansible

I run Ansible task on remote Windows hosts. I want recieve result messages by Telegram, but by default these hosts not contains python, and Telegram module don't work. How i can run it locally?
For example...

```
- hosts: winservers
  vars:
   scope: win
   script: Rulez.PS1
   folder: C:\TEMP
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
   - /etc/ansible/win/group_vars/{{ scope }}.sec
  tasks:
    - name: Сheck for path {{ folder }} availability. Create if not present.
      win_file:
       path: "{{ folder }}"
       state: directory
```

After running i want get message in Telegram: Task finished at {{ ansible_hostname }}
Try insert this code in playbook

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   telegram:
    token: 'tokentokentokentokentoken'
    chat_id: 1234567890
    msg: Task finished at {{ ansible_hostname }}
```

But it didn't work. Besides, this way i get ansible_hostname as localhost

Comment: I can run by powershell by ```Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.telegram.org/bot$($MyBotToken)/sendMessage?chat_id=$($chatID)&text=$($Message)&parse_mode=html"```

Comment: As you have given as - hosts: 127.0.0.1, ansible_hostname will give you localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as below. (not tested)

```
- hosts: winservers
  vars:
   scope: win
   script: Rulez.PS1
   folder: C:\TEMP
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
   - /etc/ansible/win/group_vars/{{ scope }}.sec
  tasks:
    - name: Сheck for path {{ folder }} availability. Create if not present.
      win_file:
       path: "{{ folder }}"
       state: directory
    - name: send a message to chat in playbook
      telegram:
       token: 'tokentokentokentokentoken'
       chat_id: 1234567890
       msg: Task finished at {{ ansible_hostname }} 
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge 'ansible_hostname' won't work if you disable gather_facts: False. and i still dont recommend to enable that option.. Try {{ hostvars['winservers']['inventory_hostname'] }} for your exact requirement.

```
- hosts: winservers
  vars:
   scope: win
   script: Rulez.PS1
   folder: C:\TEMP
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
   - /etc/ansible/win/group_vars/{{ scope }}.sec
  tasks:
    - name: Сheck for path {{ folder }} availability. Create if not present.
      win_file:
       path: "{{ folder }}"
       state: directory

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    telegram:
        token: 'tokentokentokentokentoken'
        chat_id: 1234567890
        msg: Task finished at {{ hostvars['winservers']['inventory_hostname'] }}
```